# Using Graph theory to show the resistance in an edge is ((2^n)-1)/(n*2^(n-1))

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the hypercube {0,1}<sup>n</sup>, with 2<sup>n</sup> vertices, and with edges
between vertices (a<sub>1</sub>, . . . , a<sub>n</sub>), (b<sub>1</sub>, . . . , b<sub>n</sub>) ∈ {0,1}<sup>n</sup> when they differ in exactly one coordinate.
Show that the effective resistance across an edge is 2<sup>n</sup>−1/ n2<sup>n−1</sup>

This question was on my graph theory final and I have NO idea how to approach it and solve it.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "The definition of effective resistance  stems from considering a graph, consisting of a set of nodes connected by weighted edges, to represent a network of resistors (one resistor corresponding to each edge) with resistances equal to the inverse of the corresponding edge weights. Then, the effective resistance between nodes k and j, denoted $r_{j,k}$, can be found by the resistance offered by the network when a voltage source is connected between these two nodes. "    https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.5163.pdf

Comment: Here is "[A Simple Method for Computing Resistance Distances"](http://yaroslavvb.com/papers/bapat-simple.pdf) but it doesn't look all that simple to me.

Answer (score 1):

By Foster's theorem, the sum of all effective resistances should be equal to the number of nodes in the graph minus one,  i.e., $\sum_e R_e =2^n-1$. By symmetry all edges have the same effective resistance. Since there are $n2^{n-1}$ edges, this gives the desired result